# angular2 component styleUrls not working correctly

Tags: css, angular

I have an angular2 component:

```
@Component({
    providers: [
        FlowsheetService,
        SubscriptionService
    ],
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'flowsheet',
    templateUrl: './flowsheet.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./lastRow.css']
})
```

lastRow.css in the same directory as the component file contains:

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

in my third party control there is an API that needs a css class name as return value.

that function is as follows:

```
function className() {
    return 'yellow';
}
```

I don't see anywhere showing up in yellow in my 3rd party control.

Am I coding this correctly in general?

Comment: For me at least, its not clear what is the structure of the program, what is the meaning of third party control and api and where the className() used used for and for what. Can you put a jsfiddle/plunker/codepen ?

Comment: I am using a open source grid control. I control/configure it using its custom API. One of its API functions, to customize a row color, need to receive a class name. It is a css class name. I hope that helps. Plunker is not suitable since it requires the grid source, etc...

Comment: You can check in the browser dev tools if the css files is really not loaded. If it is, you can check with the element inspector what class is put in the rows on the custom grid component and if it fits the class you are expecting. Knowing the answer to those could help understand what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax:

```
styleUrls: ['./lastRow.css']
```

Defines a style only for the template associated with this component. Is the function you defined within the component? If not, the style cannot be defined in this manner. You need to define the style for the app instead.

The Angular documentation here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html goes through how to define styles for the application instead.

Comment: the function i have defined in the component class yes but it is passed in to the third party control to use as an input parameter. So it should be working. No?